# how to stream mediaplayer over 3G/HSDPA/GPRS

Tags: java, android, 3g

I have created an app that plays my internet radio via WiFi and plays it with no problem... but when I try to use 3G/HSDPA/GPRS android mediaplayer doesn't connect or it doesn't use the 3G/HSDPA/GPRS connection. Why is that?

Any ideas on how can I use the 3G/HSDPA/GPRS to stream mp3 in android mediaplayer?

I am currently using android 2.3.

Comment: It happens to me to.... did you solve it somehow? Please, post if if you did... thanks!

Comment: yes i have solve it.. actually its automatic from the android system to use mobile data connection whenever possible example when you try to browse and your wifi is turned off it will check automatically if your mobile data connection from your network provider is available android will use it.. if not it will return an error all you have to do is handle that error or notify user or something :)